# Two players tied for second place in a timed tourney, who goes heads up?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

I have a question...
We play in a regular Texas hold ‘em  tourney, each round is timed throughout the evening, after the last round the two chip leaders go heads up for the win..fairly standard stuff.
Last night however, the timer went , there was a clear chip leader but 2 players were tied with exactly the same amount of chips.
In this situation, how would should we have decided who went into the ‘final’?
Suggested solutions were..

Three way final.

2nd & 3rd play on for a set time to decide a winner but that person only takes the chips they had when tied into the final

2nd & 3rd play for a set period of time & go into the final with whatever chip stack they have at the end of that time period.

The final round is extended for a set amount of time with all contenders playing until there are two clear finalists.

Any other suggestions or actual rules would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this is closed.  Interesting question!  Seems like it has to have come up before.  Also, this question is on topic for this site, but you might get better answers at poker.stackexchange.com which deals only with poker.

Answer (score -2):

Take the two top stacks to a final after a set period of time is a strange  tournament. Not standard stuff.  Let 2 & 3 play and take all chip to the final is not fair to 1.

A standard tournament you are out when you bust (no more chips).  If you want the tournament to end at a time range then raise the blinds every X minutes.

Say you are down to 3 and the big stack takes out 2 and 3 and they have exactly the same number of chip.  In that case in think it was be the last aggressor (open or raise).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We need to be finished by a certain time so the blinds do go up half hourly throughout the night but if the game has not reached its natural conclusion I.e everyone bust by the time the last blind round ends leaving a winner then the top two play heads up for the pot & points.

Comment: Just take  top 2 if the blinds have not reduced the field is not going to make much difference.

Comment: There was no top two...there was a clear chip leader but 2 & 3 we’re tied.

Comment: I got that part.  Just take top 2 or 3 or 4 is not going to make much difference if the blinds have not cleared the field.